# Table View и загрузка данных с сайта

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, tableview

В загрузке таблицы данных нет(не загрузились).
Источник указал сам экран(View Controller)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Запрос создается при загрузки экрана(viewDidLoad), загрузка данных асинхронная(скорее всего в этом и есть проблема)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// создаем запрос
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lineURLresult]
                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
 //создаём соединение и начинаем загрузку
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (connection) {
    // создаем NSMutableData, чтобы сохранить полученные данные
    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
}
```

Есть отдельная функция, выполняемые при завершении загрузки, в которой данные загрузились(существуют в receivedData)

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {}
```

а в функции заполнения таблицы данных нет(receivedData пуст) :(

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

Как загрузить данные в таблицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `NSURLConnection` уже устарел для использования в iOS проектах, с минимальной версией 6.0. Вместо него можно использовать `NSURLSession`. Ниже приведены примеры реализации простых **HTTP GET** запросов:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lineURLresult]];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse
*response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            if (connectionError || !data) {
                // connection error or emty response  -> show alert with error
            } else {
                NSError *parseError;
                NSArray *jsonList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
                   if (parseError || !jsonList) {
                       // parsing error -> show alert with error
                   } else {
                       tableViewData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:jsonList];
                       [tableView reloadData];
                   }
                });
            }
        }];


[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lineURLresult] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError * connectionError) {
    if (connectionError || !data) {
        // connection error or emty response  -> show alert with error
    } else {
        NSError *parseError;
        NSArray *jsonList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
             if (parseError || !jsonList) {
                 // parsing error -> show alert with error
             } else {
                 tableViewData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:jsonList];
                 [tableView reloadData];
             }
        });
    }
}] resume];
```

Что бы установить или обновить данные в `TableView`, необходимо в классе делегата  (в вашем примере это класс `View Controller`) реализовать методы:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //  Поучаем обьект данных tableViewData[indexPath.row] и накладываем на представление ячейки таблицы cell
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableViewData count];
}

- (void)downloadDataFromServer()
{
    //Используем один из блоков ниже для загрузки данных
}
```

> Данные таблицы NSMutableArray *tableViewData; - обьявить полем класса
>   `View Controller`. После изменения обьекта массива данных
>   tableViewData необходимо вызывать метод **[tableView reloadData];**

Comment: В NSURLSession на строке "tableViewData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:jsonList];" программа падает и попадает в  некий Thread 7 "0x385358a <+10>: jae    0x385359a                 ; <+26>". 

И еще, где должен находится GET запрос, чтобы видна была функция  [tableView reloadData]?  В загрузки экрана(где я делал запрос ранее), ее нет, а в cellForRowAtIndexPath будет вызывать этот запрос многократно

Comment: 1) Когда приложение падает, смотрите логи и там будем информация о причине креша; это может быть попытка создания массива из  nill объекта или jsonList - не является объектом класса NSArray. 2) Вам нужно объявить ссылку на __weak IBOutlet UITableView *tableView; в поле класса, и в файле интерфейса storyboard установить связь между представлением таблицы и полем в классе. После этого вы можете использовать ссылку на UITableView  внутри вашего класса и затем, например, реализовать метогд - (void)downloadDataFromServer(), внутри которого вставить блок для загрузки данных.